# When deleting the post How to delete all related comments , likes and notifications in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to delete all related data when I delete a post. All comments likes and all notifications related to this post are also deleted when I delete this post. How can I do this ? I do that when a user delets all his posts, buckets, comments, and reported users is also deleted. Here is the Code of this. But i also want to delete all the things related to the post like notifications, likes etc. Please help.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->posts()->forceDelete();
    $user->buckets()->forceDelete();
    $user->comments()->forceDelete();
    $user->reportedUser()->forceDelete();

    $user->forceDelete();

    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('Success','User Deleted Successfully');
}
```

This code delete all the things that relates to user when user is deleted but i also want to delete all things related to post. How i can do this?

Comment: Can you add the `Post` model so we can see what is related to the post.

Comment: Why did you not set `->onDelete('cascade')` on your migration ? check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('bucket_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('buckets')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: I use on delete cascade @JulienMetral

Comment: In my post model user, bucket and comments relate @thisiskelvin

Comment: If ever a `Post` is deleted by itself, should the relations also be deleted? If so, I will add an answer

Comment: Yeah i want when I deleted a Post all likes , notifications related to this post is also deleted

Comment: have you added all the `onDelete('cascade')`  for each relation (posts, comments, reported) ? if you have done this, you should be able to delete the user and the delete will automaticly remove relationship records

Comment: I use Queable notifications and its can not be deleted @JulienMetral

Comment: @Moaiz Which version of laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.5.44 @thisiskelvin

Answer (score 4):

You can [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) to trigger off an action once the `Post` record is being deleted. In your `Post` model, you can add a `$dispatchesEvents` property:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'deleting' => \App\Events\PostDeleting::class,
];
```

After this, you can create the new event:

```
php artisan make:event PostDeleting
```

A new event file should be added (`app\events\PostDeleting.php`).

Here you can define the data which will be passed to the event listener.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class PostDeleting
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $post;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param \App\Post $post
     */
    public function __construct(Post $post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }
}
```

After this, you will need to create the **event listener** (which will listen out for the post being deleted):

```
php artisan event:listener PostDeleting
```

This will create a listener (`app/listeners/PostDeleting.php`). Here, you define the functionality which is ran once the `Post` is deleting (this uses the variable defined in the **event**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\PostDeleting as PostDeletingEvent;

class PostDeleting
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Events\PostDeleting $event
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(PostDeletingEvent $event)
    {
        $event->user->likes()->delete(); // or whatever relation you need to delete.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for polymorphic relations because with notifications I use polymorphic relations @thisiskelvin

Comment: @Moaiz I would guess as long as relations are set correctly it should work as planned.

Comment: I don't find any solution about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set in your migrations

E.g. `comments` migration

```
$table->foreign('post_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('posts')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

No need to write any other logic. you can write something like that on your relational migration

For polymorphic relationship E.g.

`Post Model`

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($post) {
        $post->comments()->delete();
        // ...
    });

}
```

or
You can manage by [Cascade polymorphic delete](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-cascade-deletes) package

Comment: Is there any idea about polymorphic relations because i use polymorphic relations with notifications ? @bhavinjr

Comment: One thing more i use the built in library for notifications. Any idea about that to delete notification also if post deleted @bhavinjr

Comment: if notification is related to post then you can use delete method after comments delete. or let me know your notification model relationship

Comment: trait HasDatabaseNotifications
{
    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(DatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

Comment: This is the file that notification library create @bhavinjr